# PHP: Missing mbstring in pcf

Tags: php, devops, grav

I've been at this all day with no solution. It's easy to run locally, but trying to get this running on Pivotal Cloud Foundry has been a different challenge.

I've been trying to get Grav-CMS (https://getgrav.org/) deployed onto PCF.

I'm close, but I'm running into a dependency error. I'm using the PHP buildpack on 7.3.13

When I try to run php bin/grav install (or php bin/grav ), I get the error :

`'mbstring' extension is not loaded.  This is required for Grav to run correctly`

.

I looked up documentation for how to get these libraries included.

what i've done:
1) in .bp-config/options.json, you can add "mbstring" to "PHP_EXTENSIONS"
2) in .bp-config, added directory and file php/php.ini.d/extra.ini

my extra.ini looks like this:

```
[PHP]
extension=mbstring
extension=mbstring.so
```

Any input? I'm trying to get this grav-cms hosted

Comment: What OS are you running this on?

Comment: cf version 6.49.0+d0dfa93bb.2020-01-07


"build": "2.7.9-build.21",


cli version: 6.23.0


Some version of linux. Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic Beaver) in specific

Comment: Try running `php -i | grep mbstring` to see what it says. Also, run `php -i | grep ini` to make 100% certain what ini files are being parsed. It is also possible to have two configs, one for CLI and one for web, and it is possible for these to get out out sync.

Comment: Thanks for the response.

On |grep mbstring, it does locate this command: '--enable-mbstring=shared'

on grep | ini, it does give the location of the php.ini file: /tmp/build/391e1b0b/binary-builder/ports/x86_64-linux-gnu/php7/7.3.13/lib

Comment: Also. Might help. I've been calling php (inside the pcf container) directly from the installed directory. `app/php/bin/php` 

so my command to run grav would be `../php/bin/php bin/grav`